# Position absolute div inside wrapper parameters

Tags: css

I have some elements I have to place in my webpage with a fixed position using `position:absolute`. The point is that it works very well on my screen, but when I test it on another screen with different resolution, it looks misplaced, even if I put these absolutely positioned `divs` inside the page wrapper.

Here are my elements:

```
 <div id="wrapper3" class="clearfix">
     <div style="border:1px solid #000; width:682px; height:489px; position:absolute; left:116px; top:209px"></div>
     <div style="border:1px solid #000; width:336px; height:240px; position:absolute; left:806px; top:209px"></div>
     <div style="border:1px solid #000; width:336px; height:241px; position:absolute; left:806px; top:457px"></div>
 </div>
```

These elements are black frames.

Is there another way around this? I know `position:relative` works in similar fashion, but I need `absolute`. I just need it to fit in every screen resolution.

Comment: do not link to your personal website: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it use jsfiddle.net instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should assign `position:relative;` to the wrapper3 div in order of positioning the frames respect to its parent.

Answer (score 1):

Make the containing div of the elements `position: relative;` Then position the children relative to it, not the body.